File returning IActionResult works on local but not when deployed
I have this code which i create a pdf and then return it to show. It works on my local, it opens pdf as result of that controller but when i publish it deploy to hosting same url gives HTTP500 error so it does not download/show anything. I think it is about some permissions on IIS, i wrote to hosting but for now they don't seem to accept/ try to control it. What do you think? this is my code:
public IActionResult downloadLabels()
    {
        try
        {
            var printdate = DateTime.Now;
            var uname = HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name).Value;
            var labels = _context.Labels
                                .Where(w => w.Status == "Print")
                                .Include(i => i.OrderNavigation)
                                .ToList();

            if (labels.Count > 0)
            {
                return Json("buldun");

                string webRootPath = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;
                string directoryPath = Path.Combine(webRootPath);
                string fileName = DateTime.Now.ToString().Replace(".", "-").Replace(":", "-") + "_" + uname + "_labels.pdf";
                string filePath = Path.Combine(directoryPath, fileName);
                using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))

                {

                    int pagenumber = 1;
                    Document document = new Document();
                    //string desktopPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
                    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fileStream);

                    //PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(@"C:\Users\abdul\Desktop\" + uname + "_labels.pdf", FileMode.Create));

                    document.Open();
                    int check = 1;
                    foreach (var label in labels)
                    {
                        var lblcnt = _context.Labels.Where(w => w.OrderId == label.OrderId).ToList().Count();

                        if (label.Platform != "Walmart")
                        {
                            byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(label.Image.Split(",")[1]);
                            Image img = Image.GetInstance(bytes);

                            img.ScaleToFit(document.PageSize.Width - document.LeftMargin - document.RightMargin, document.PageSize.Height - document.TopMargin - document.BottomMargin);

                            document.NewPage();
                            document.Add(img);

                            if (check == lblcnt)
                            {
                                document.NewPage();

                                var pageNumberPhrase = new Phrase(pagenumber.ToString());
                                pageNumberPhrase.Font = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 10, Font.BOLD);
                                var pageNumberParagraph = new Paragraph(pageNumberPhrase);
                                pageNumberParagraph.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
                                document.Add(pageNumberParagraph);
                                iTextSharp.text.pdf.draw.LineSeparator line = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.draw.LineSeparator
                                {
                                    LineWidth = 1,
                                    LineColor = BaseColor.BLACK
                                };
                                document.Add(new Chunk("\n"));

                                document.Add(new Paragraph(label.OrderNavigation.Address, FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 18)));

                                document.Add(new Chunk("\n"));
                                document.Add(line);
                                document.Add(new Chunk("\n"));

                                var barcodeWriter = new ZXing.Windows.Compatibility.BarcodeWriter
                                {
                                    Format = BarcodeFormat.CODE_128,
                                    Options = new ZXing.Common.EncodingOptions
                                    {
                                        Height = 130,
                                        Width = 600,
                                        NoPadding = true,

                                    }

                                };
                                var barcodeImage = barcodeWriter.Write(label.OrderNavigation.OrderNumber);

                                // Convert the barcode image to bitmap
                                var barcodeBitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(barcodeImage);
                                iTextSharp.text.Image barcodeImg = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(barcodeBitmap, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
                                document.Add(barcodeImg);

                                //var myBarcode = BarcodeWriter.CreateBarcode(label.OrderNavigation.OrderNumber, BarcodeWriterEncoding.Code128);
                                //myBarcode.ResizeTo(500, 100);
                                //myBarcode.AddBarcodeValueTextBelowBarcode();
                                //var barbytes = myBarcode.ToPngBinaryData();
                                //Image imgb = Image.GetInstance(barbytes);
                                //document.Add(imgb);

                                var items = labels.Where(w => w.OrderId == label.OrderId).GroupBy(g => g.Title).Select(s => s.First()).ToList();
                                foreach (var item in items)
                                {
                                    document.Add(new Chunk("\n"));

                                    document.Add(line);
                                    document.Add(new Chunk("\n"));

                                    document.Add(new Paragraph(label.Title, FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 18)));
                                    document.Add(new Chunk("x" + label.OrderNavigation.Quantity.ToString(), FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 30)));

                                    document.Add(new Chunk("\n"));
                                    document.Add(new Chunk("\n"));

                                    document.Add(line);
                                    document.Add(new Chunk("\n"));

                                    document.Add(new Paragraph("SKU: " + label.Sku, FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 16)));

                                }
                                document.Add(new Chunk("\n"));

                                document.Add(line);

                                document.Add(new Chunk("\n"));
                                document.Add(new Paragraph("Label Count: " + lblcnt.ToString(), FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 18)));
                                pagenumber++;
                                check = 1; ;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                check++;
                            }

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(label.Image);
                            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(bytes);
                            for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
                            {
                                PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, i);
                                document.NewPage();

                                Rectangle pageSize = reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(i);

                                float scaleX = (document.PageSize.Width - document.LeftMargin - document.RightMargin) / pageSize.Width;
                                float scaleY = (document.PageSize.Height - document.TopMargin - document.BottomMargin) / pageSize.Height;
                                float scale = Math.Min(scaleX, scaleY);

                                float offsetX = (document.PageSize.Width - (pageSize.Width * scale)) / 2;
                                float offsetY = (document.PageSize.Height - (pageSize.Height * scale)) / 2;

                                PdfContentByte contentByte = writer.DirectContent;
                                contentByte.AddTemplate(page, scale, 0, 0, scale, offsetX, offsetY);
                            }
                            if (check == lblcnt)
                            {
                                document.NewPage();
                                iTextSharp.text.pdf.draw.LineSeparator line = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.draw.LineSeparator
                                {
                                    LineWidth = 1,
                                    LineColor = BaseColor.BLACK
                                };

                                var pageNumberPhrase = new Phrase(pagenumber.ToString());
                                pageNumberPhrase.Font = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 10, Font.BOLD);
                                var pageNumberParagraph = new Paragraph(pageNumberPhrase);
                                pageNumberParagraph.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
                                document.Add(pageNumberParagraph);

                                document.Add(new Chunk("\n"));

                                document.Add(new Paragraph(label.OrderNavigation.Address, FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 18)));

                                document.Add(new Chunk("\n"));
                                document.Add(line);
                                document.Add(new Chunk("\n"));


                                var barcodeWriter = new ZXing.Windows.Compatibility.BarcodeWriter
                                {
                                    Format = BarcodeFormat.CODE_128,
                                    Options = new ZXing.Common.EncodingOptions
                                    {
                                        Height = 130,
                                        Width = 600,
                                        NoPadding = true,

                                    }

                                };
                                var barcodeImage = barcodeWriter.Write(label.OrderNavigation.OrderNumber);

                                // Convert the barcode image to bitmap
                                var barcodeBitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(barcodeImage);
                                iTextSharp.text.Image barcodeImg = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(barcodeBitmap, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
                                document.Add(barcodeImg);

                                var items = labels.Where(w => w.OrderId == label.OrderId).GroupBy(g => g.Title).Select(s => s.First()).ToList();
                                foreach (var item in items)
                                {
                                    document.Add(new Chunk("\n"));

                                    document.Add(line);
                                    document.Add(new Chunk("\n"));

                                    document.Add(new Paragraph(label.Title, FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 18)));
                                    document.Add(new Chunk("x" + label.OrderNavigation.Quantity.ToString(), FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 30)));

                                    document.Add(new Chunk("\n"));
                                    document.Add(new Chunk("\n"));

                                    document.Add(line);
                                    document.Add(new Chunk("\n"));

                                    document.Add(new Paragraph("SKU: " + label.Sku, FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 16)));

                                }
                                document.Add(new Chunk("\n"));

                                document.Add(line);

                                document.Add(new Chunk("\n"));
                                document.Add(new Paragraph("Label Count: " + lblcnt.ToString(), FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 18)));
                                pagenumber++;
                                check = 1;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                check++;
                            }
                        }
                        if(uname != "admin")
                        {
                            label.Status = "Labeled";
                            label.PrintDate = printdate;
                            _context.SaveChanges();
                        }

                    }

                    document.Close();

                    byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
                    //Response.Headers["Content-Disposition"] = "inline;filename=" + fileName;
                    //Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                    return File(fileBytes, "application/pdf",fileName);


                }


            }
            return Json("No Labels to Print");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return Json(e.Message.ToString());
        }
    }

and this is how i route it:
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" onclick="downloadLabels()">
        <i class="fa-file-pdf"></i>Get Labels
    </a>
</li>
function downloadLabels() {
    window.open("/Amazon/downloadLabels", "_blank");
}


If you have a 500 error, then you should have an exception and full stack trace in a log file somewhere. That's the quickest way to work out what went wrong.

@JeremyLakeman i put try catch all around my code but it does not start to work on the code it gives 500 directly, hosting said to me that they gave me permission to create virtual directory so i changed my code according to it. I updated my code. But like i said i put a json return right start of  the function but it did not even show up it is directly 500.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/troubleshoot-azure-iis?view=aspnetcore-7.0#aspnet-core-module-stdout-log-iis
